# Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript - 404 on method call

Tags: javascript, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, client-library

Since this morning all my applications using gapi are down.

I'm using:
https://apis.google.com/js/client.js

to communicate with the Endpoints of my Google Appengine applications, for example:

```
gapi.client.load('public', 'v2', function(){
    gapi.client.public.organizations().execute(function(response){ 
        console.log(response); 
    }); 
}, 'https://XXX.appspot.com/_ah/api');
```

As of today all calls are responded with the following error message:

```
[{"error":{"code":404,"message":"Not Found","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"notFound","message":"Not Found"}]},"id":"gapiRpc"}]
```

My applications are not logging any errors.
I can reach the Endpoint API explorer (/_ah/api/explorer) without errors.
I can make HTTP-request calls without errors, e.g

```
https://XXX.appspot.com/_ah/api/public/v2/organizations
```

The "gapi"-object is loaded without errors. My "public" endpoint is also loaded and I can list all methods using the javascript console.

I have reported this error to Google.

Anybody else having this issue? Does anybody have any quick solutions or workarounds? Have I perhaps missed some Google updates or API-changes?

Thanks

Comment: Same issues for me. And the Google appengine dashboard does not report any problem

Comment: Google have confirmed that there is a problem. You can follow the issue here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/eLKrUDOhMTo I recommend everyone to subscribe to the Google App Engine Downtime Notify group if you haven't done so already - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine-downtime-notify

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved. My applications are back up again!

From Goolgle support:
"Google API JavaScript client functionality has already been restored for some users, and we expect a resolution for all users in the near future. Please note this time frame is an estimate and may change."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a general issue with the JS Client library at the moment, not limited to Endpoints APIs, but affecting all Google APIs.

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=136

Only real "work around" is not to depend on the JS Client Library (which had stability issues in the past as well) and construct the HTTP Requests yourself, which I know isn't a quick solution.

You can also try using the [`gapi.client.request`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientrequest) method for direct REST requests which seems to be working for one of my endpoints APIs. (again, not a quick solution, but probably better/easier since you still have the authentication working via the client library).

```
gapi.client.request({
  "path": "/public/v2/organizations",
  "root": "https://XXX.appspot.com/_ah/api"
}).execute(function (response) { 
  console.log(response); 
});
```

Edit: Update from the linked issue

They will be rolling back the broken update which will take several hours to complete (no exact ETA yet).

As a "quick" fix you can explicitely add the apiVersion to each request (careful: the `B` might change after the rollback, but it works now):

```
var request = gapi.client.public.organizations();
request.B.apiVersion = "v2";
request.execute(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Edit 2: Everything seems to be back to normal now.

Comment: True, I think I'll have to write my own request wrappers to avoid suck errors in the future. I'm in an early stage of production so its no too much to rewrite. Thanks for the tip on the "gapi.client.request", that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The another workaround can be done by passing discovery document url.
Sample discovery document url is

- url =
  http://[application-id].appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/[endpoint-api-name]/v1/rest
- localHostURL =
  http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/[endpoint-api-name]/v1/rest

Example :-

window.gapi.client.load("http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/[endpoint-api-name]/v1/rest").then(() => { Your promise return callback function })

or

window.gapi.client.load(" http://[application-id].appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/[endpoint-api-name]/v1/rest").then(() => { Your promise return callback function })